# A book to increase statistical problem solving skills

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references

I would like to have from you any suggestion about a specific book on statistics. I am a physicist, which means I already have a background in statistics and many other quantitative disciplines. My problem is that statistics has never been the main topic of any exam I did. Which means I already have a knowledge about this discipline but I fill a little failing in problem solving.

The book I believe is the right one for me should be mainly about exercises, in order to increase my problem solving skills, should have a somehow intriguing character, as at the moment statistics is not much more than an hobby, but should also be correlated with theory, in order to properly fill the gap I may have in the theory.

Any suggestion about that?

Comment: [Here!](https://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Statistics is a big area; you could easily spend decades covering the current state of knowledge, and by the time you were finished there'd be those decades of new things that were developed in the meantime. What sorts of problems/theory do you want to cover?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One fun book to start with is

[image]

See https://bookshop.org/books/fifty-challenging-problems-in-probability-with-solutions/9780486653556.  To solve this problems you need to think in a statistical or probabilistic way!

Answer (score 3):

- I would suggest a great book about theoretical statistics with methods which have lots of intriguing problems in various topics on Statistics:
  **Mathematical Statistics: Basic Ideas and Selected Topics** (Chapman & Hall/CRC Texts in Statistical Science) by **Bickel and Doksum** [https://www.amazon.com/dp/1498740316/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1498740316).
  One of our teachers suggested this book. I have only read Volume 1 though - I don't know much about Volume 2.
- Otherwise, you can have the classic book: **Statistical Inference** by *Casella and Berger*.
- If you want to know more about probability, you may look at *An intermediate course in probability* or *Probability: A Graduate Course* by *Allan Gut* or other classic probability books.

The books I mentioned have many intriguing problems, but might be little 'new' to the newcomers in statistics. But as you have some knowledge of Statistics, I would strongly recommend the first book.

Answer (score 1):

As a former Physicist myself, I very much sympathise with your desire to increase your statistical problem solving skills.

I'd like to recommend the brilliant

[image]

Don't let the playful tone of the book fool you: Despite (?) the sparsity of mathematical derivations in this book, it covers topics & models that lead to complex and highly non-trivial results. In my opinion McElreath manages to redefine and teach statistical problem solving in a way that was entirely missing from the stats courses I took as a Physics graduate 20 years ago.
McElreath's focus is on statistical modelling, model validation and exploring/questioning possible data generating processes, with plenty of examples & exercises to work through in R.

The book also comes highly recommended by [Andrew Gelman and Stan colleagues](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2016/01/15/mcelreaths-statistial-rethinking-a-bayesian-course-with-examples-in-r-and-stan/).